# Problem with ortho projection and pcolormesh in matplotlib-basemap

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, orthographic

I have trouble with the ortho projection and pcolormesh.

It should plot a mesh of grid points. Instead, in the upper right portion of the sphere it plots strange lines instead of grid points. The mapping of the mesh looks off.

I tried the code below.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.clf()

dpp =1 # degrees per pixel
lons = np.arange(-180,180+dpp,dpp)
lats = -1*np.arange(-90,90+dpp,dpp)

m = Basemap(projection='ortho', lon_0=0, lat_0=-60, resolution='l')
data = np.random.random((np.size(lats), np.size(lons)))
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
x, y = m(lons, lats)

im = m.pcolormesh(x, y, data, latlon=False, cmap='RdBu')
#im = m.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data, latlon=True, cmap='RdBu')

m.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

I obtain the following plot:

[image: Output of the code]

The random noise should be mapped onto the entire sphere, but there is clearly an error in the upper right of the ortho map.

Does anyone else get this error with the included code?

Comment: You have data for the full globe, so the pcolormesh continues "behind" the globe. You would need all data that is not to be shown to be masked out. This is a bit easier for a globe centered at `lon_0=0, lat_0=0` than for the shifted one.

Comment: So the ortho projection in basemap basically isn't compatable with pcolormesh without creating a custom mask for the data? Seems like a big oversight. I shouldn't need to compute a custom mask just to plot data on a ortho projection.

The [example](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/ortho.html) plotting continents doesn't have this issue (although it doesn't use pcolormesh).

Is there an alternative that allows me to plot a grid of data on an ortho projection?

Comment: In principle everything you plot will be shown. So I wouldn't blame basemap for doing what it's being asked to do.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that cartopy has a different approach by working with different projections that handle the data themselves. I guess it would make sense to see how cartopy behaves in this case, and possibly adapt the code for cartopy in the future.

Comment: Basemap is not doing what it is asked to do. The [basemap documentation for an ortho projection](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/ortho.html) does not show objects plotted on the opposite side of the sphere. The expected behavior for plotting data on an ortho projection is to only show that data on the visible side of the map. I will look into cartopy.

Comment: The example doesn't show any custom plot. You may try out a line plot, like `m.plot(x,y)` - it will also show [unwanted lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfKTa.png). This is because the "backside parts" are filtered outcorrectly, but the line continues between the last two visible points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since basemap would require you to manually filter out unwanted data (those that are "behind the globe"), here is how to do the same with cartopy.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

proj = ccrs.Orthographic(central_longitude=0.0, central_latitude=-60.0)

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)

dpp =1 
lons = np.arange(-180,180+dpp,dpp)
lats = 1*np.arange(-90,90+dpp,dpp)
data = np.random.random((np.size(lats), np.size(lons)))
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
im = ax.pcolormesh(lons, lats, data, cmap='RdBu', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')
ax.gridlines()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A fix to Basemap was suggested in the github basemap thread [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/470#issuecomment-524545424)